# How to dynamically build nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm getting data from an api and want to format the data in a way that the client side can read.

I've tried the following code to build up the object, but it feels hacky and doesn't take care of edge cases.

```
function myHackyFunction(data){
result = {}

data.forEach(el => {
        const timeStamp = el['time']
        result[timeStamp] = { teacher: null, student: null }
    })
data.forEach(el => {
        const role = el['role']
        const timeStamp = el['time']
        const age = el['age']
        if (role.includes('teacher')) {
            result[timeStamp].teacher = age
        }
        if (role.includes('student')) {
            result[timeStamp].student = age
        }
    })
  return result
}
myHackyFunction(data)
```

The data variable will have different length, but always the same setup. Sometimes it includes both the `student` and `teacher` role, sometimes just one of them.

this data..

```
const data = [
  {
    time: 2019,
    role: 'student',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    time: 2019,
    role: 'teacher',
    age: 37
  },
  {
    time: 2020,
    role: 'teacher',
    age: 45
  }
]
```

..should look like:

```
const desiredData = {
  2019: {
    student: 22,
    teacher: 37
  },
  2020: {
    student: null,
    teacher: 45
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you see data that looks like your grouping etc, `Array.reduce` would normally fit the bill.

eg.

```js
const data = [
  {
    time: 2019,
    role: 'student',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    time: 2019,
    role: 'teacher',
    age: 37
  },
  {
    time: 2020,
    role: 'teacher',
    age: 45
  }
];
//..should look like:

const desiredData = data.reduce((a, v) => {
  a[v.time] = a[v.time] || {student: null, teacher: null};
  a[v.time][v.role] = v.age;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(desiredData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution below for the problem:

```js
console.clear()

const data = [
  {
    time: 2019,
    role: 'student',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    time: 2019,
    role: 'teacher',
    age: 37
  },
  {
    time: 2020,
    role: 'teacher',
    age: 45
  }
]

const m = {}
const len = data.length

for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if (!m[data[i].time]) m[data[i].time] = {student: null, teacher: null}
  if (data[i].role === 'student')
    m[data[i].time].student = data[i].age
  else if (data[i].role === 'teacher')
    m[data[i].time].teacher = data[i].age 
}

console.log(m)
```

**Note**: This will only work if there is one student/teacher in a given year, otherwise the value will be overridden.